# Why does git-bash show this every time on startup?

Tags: path, git-bash

When I open git-bash, it shows `bash:Path XXXXX no such file and directory`
but I can use every command, can somebody tell me why?

[image]

Comment: Show us your `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`.

Comment: @phd thanks i found the problem, i miss the .bash_profile in user root and i add a new one it works.